# Sqlite code for Select primary key and foreign key table data for display all data in detailview in iphone application

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to implement Primary Key and Foreign Key Table Data in Class Structure in Iphone Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213732/how-to-implement-primary-key-and-foreign-key-table-data-in-class-structure-in-iph)

How to Select Foreign Key and Primary Key table data for display all data into detailviewcontroller Of rootTableView using this query

```
select 
    TaskId, TaskName, Category, StartDate, DueDate, Status 
from 
    ToDo, Category 
Where 
    ToDo.TaskId = Category.TaskId.
```

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

```
    //const char *sql = "select TaskId,TaskName,StartDate,DueDate,Status,CategoryId from ToDo";

    const char *sql = "SELECT TaskId,TaskName,StartDate,DueDate,Status,ToDo.CategoryId,CategoryName FROM ToDo LEFT OUTER JOIN Category ON ToDo.CategoryId=Category.CategoryId";

    sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
            ToDo *toDoObj = [[ToDo alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];
            toDoObj.taskName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];
            toDoObj.startDate = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 2)];
            toDoObj.dueDate = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 3)];
            toDoObj.status  = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 4);
            toDoObj.categoryId = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 5);
            toDoObj.category = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 6)];
            toDoObj.isDirty = NO;

            [appDelegate.todoArray addObject:toDoObj];
            [toDoObj release];
        }
    }

}
else
    sqlite3_close(database);
```

Comment: After All i got its myself so its help some one...